# How can I find many sums in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have a large array, which I have simplified for the question purpose

```
[
  {"item1": 3, "item40": 2},
  {"item1": 4, "item40": 8}
]
```

I would like to end up with this, which is the sum of each similar property in the array of objects. I tried a lot. Doing a forEach whith a forIn inside. But I am stuck. Please help :)

[5, 12]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the result. Traverse the array using map, get the object values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and at last, sum the values using reduce.

```js
const data = [
  { item1: 3, item40: 2 },
  { item1: 4, item40: 8 },
];
const ret = data.map((x) => Object.values(x).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0));
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: super quick answer. I forgot one thing. the numbers are actually string values

Comment: If input numbers are string then use this `data.map((x) => Object.values(x).reduce((p, c) => p + +c, 0))`

Answer (score 2):

This leverages [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the values in the array, then gets uses [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values in each object as an array and [`.reduce`] to sum them:

```js
const arr = [
  {"item1": 3, "item40": 2},
  {"item1": 4, "item40": 8}
];

const result = arr.map((obj) => Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0));

console.log(result);
```